# How to bind two columns values in dropdown with separate comma(,)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a asp.net application in that I am using ado.net entity framework in which I want to bind the two column in that dropdown.for example:

in database their two column of First_name ,Last_name .I want these two columns value come in a single dropdown using C#.

How to do that?

```
public void BindClients()
{
    //To Bind the Client Names for Searching Option
    var ddlclientnames = (from ddl in mortgageentity.Clients select ddl).ToList();
    if (ddlclientnames.Count() > 0)
    {
        ddlsearchclient.DataSource = ddlclientnames;
        ddlsearchclient.DataValueField = "Client_ID";
        ddlsearchclient.DataTextField = "LastName";
        ddlsearchclient.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework are you using? Which version of .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you use the Fullname a lot, I would suggest to use an anonymous type in your select.

This also limits the amount of data that will be done in your select and other overhead.

```
var ddlclientnames = (from ddl in mortgageentity.Clients 
                select new { id = ..., FullName = FirstName + Lastname}.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is define a custom property on the Object that does this for you:

**Edited for clarity with your objects**

You would write something like

```
public partial class Clients
{
    public string FullName
    {
       get { return String.Format("{0}, {1}", LastName, FirstName); }
    }

}
```

This will give you a read only property `FullName` on the `Clients` Entity.

Then you can do the following

```
public void BindClients()
{
    //To Bind the Client Names for Searching Option
    var ddlclientnames = (from ddl in mortgageentity.Clients select ddl).ToList();
    if (ddlclientnames.Any)
    {
        ddlsearchclient.DataSource = ddlclientnames;
        ddlsearchclient.DataValueField = "Client_ID";
        ddlsearchclient.DataTextField = "FullName";
        ddlsearchclient.DataBind();
    }

}
```

I'd also suggest the use of the `Any` method instead of `ddlclientname.Count > 0` as it doesn't require enumerating the entire collection.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    ddl.Items.Clear();
    foreach (var item in myCollection)
    {
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.FirstName + "," + item.LastName, item.ID));
    }
```

Comment: Hi thank you for giving a response,How can i find datatextfiled and datavaluefiled please tellme.

Comment: the first parameter of `ListItem` contractor is the item text and the second parameter is a the item value so you don't need `DataTextFiled` and `DataValueFiled` attributes in your aspx

Answer (score 0):

DataSet ds = MyDataSet();

```
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            dropLojas.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLUNA1"].ToString() + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLUNA2"].ToString() + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLUNA3"].ToString());
            dropLojas.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLUNA1"].ToString();

        }
```

You can do best with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void BindSalesOrganization()
{
    IList<Customer> objCustomerList = (new CustomerFacade()).GetAllSalesOrgByUserCode(SessionManager.UserCode);
    if (objCustomerList != null && objCustomerList.Count >= 0)
    {
        ddlSalesOrg.Items.Clear();
        ddlSalesOrg.DataSource = objCustomerList;
        ddlSalesOrg.DataTextField = "SalesOrganization";
        ddlSalesOrg.DataValueField = "SalesOrgCode";
        ddlSalesOrg.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetAllSalesOrgsByUserCode]                                    
@UserCode VARCHAR(50)                                          
AS                                          
BEGIN                            

SELECT S.code,'[' +  S.Code + '] '+ S.[Description]   AS description  FROM tblSalesOrganization S         
WHERE S.IsActive=1           

END
```